# How can I hide the toolbar of a UINavigationController using storyboards?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a storyboard iOS app that has a number of views I push through. I have a UINavigationController with the "Shows Toolbar" option selected, which then populates throughout my view hierarchy.

Say my view flow is 3 views, A, B, and C:

```
View A --(push)--> View B --(push)--> View C
```

View A is a normal view controller, with a button on the toolbar used to push View B.
View B is a table controller, so I want to hide the toolbar here.
View C is another view like View A, with a toolbar required to be shown.

In Xcode/Storyboard, if in View B I select the "Hides bottom bar on push" it does exactly that - the bottom bar is hidden for View B. Similarly if I choose 'None' for the 'Bottom bar' select option, there's no bar for View B. Good.

Here's my problem: No matter what I do, using either option for view B, my toolbar doesn't come back for view C. If I set View C's toolbar as inferred (and uncheck hide on push) it doesn't show, nor if I set it manually to 'Toolbar'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As @Zoltán said, Storyboard doesn't provide the complete answer.

Setting self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES/NO on viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear is functional, but ugly (a black rectangle appears in place of the toolbar during the view transition animation).

Here's what I did for the View B controller (and the inverse for View C) to mimic the animation smoothness of the "hide on push" option in the storyboard:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Did you include [super viewWillAppear:animated] and [super viewWillDisappear:animated]?

Comment: Do not forget to call super's viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear!

Comment: Perfect! In Swift:                              self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can do it purely in The Storyboard. However you can just set it to display always, put the buttons on it for every view you want it to appear in and you can call 
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES; when a viewcontroller is loaded in which you dont want the toolbar to appear.
After that if another VC appears on which you do want the toolbar, just set toolbarHidden to NO.

Comment: This works, just.

It gives on transition an ugly black mark where the toolbar has disappeared. But it's right in terms of the code needed, and the inability for Storyboards to provide the entire thing.