# Root child view not sized properly when displayed by navigation controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder

I have a root view in a navigation controller that isn't conforming to the right length and I don't know how to fix it using IB.
[Here](http://youtu.be/JGk4UYRbjoc) is a short clip showing what's happening (the attributes inspector shown in the video are of the navigation controller connected to this issue).

The view hierarchy is displayed below with the view I deem is the problem outlined in blue. It's not stretching to the bottom which is why I deduct the black bar is displaying underneath it. Any suggestions?

[image: view debugger view hierarchy photo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, I used the view debugger to capture the view hierarchy of both another navigation push segue that was working properly and this one. This showed me that the black rectangle area was reserved for showing a UIToolbar. Since you can't hide or show toolbars currently using IB, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840629/how-can-i-hide-the-toolbar-of-a-uinavigationcontroller-using-storyboards) and then just translated it to Swift. I put the following code in my child UIViewController:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
}
```

This eliminated the black rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Try this setup

embed entry view in tab bar, then embed the view in navigation controller and segue a button to the next view (need +1 more to post an image :( )

Hey man some wild guesses here. In ever had this problem before but...

1.Have you setup auto layout ?
2.Also what's your child view controller , is it just a generic view controller?

3.what's the segue you are using ? 
4. Did you embed it in navigation view controller ?

Comment: I have auto layout set up and the child view controller is just a generic view controller. I embedded the child view controller within the navigation controller. What are you referring to by _entry view_?